# Parse Object throws unrecognized selector when I set a property value

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery, back4app

I am using Parse with ObjectiveC to store some information about a color theme. Here is my current PFObject model:

CloudThemes.h

```
#import "Parse/Parse.h"
@interface CloudThemes : PFObject<PFSubclassing>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary <NSString *, NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *> * themes;

@end
```

CloudThemes.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "CloudThemes.h"
#import "Constants.h"

@implementation CloudThemes

    @dynamic themes;

+ (nonnull NSString *)parseClassName {
    return kCloudThemesModelClassName;
}
@end
```

Whenever I try to give my themes object a value, it rejects it, with an error saying

```
-[CloudThemes setThemes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x283be0000
```

on the line `themes.themes = myTheme;`

```
    CloudThemes * themes = [[CloudThemes alloc] initWithClassName:kCloudThemesModelClassName];
    
    NSDictionary * myTheme = @{@"Cloud": @{@"Background" : @"FEFFFF", @"Secondary" : @"EAEAEA",
                                           @"Label" : @"170A4E", @"Accent" : @"2E6C8B",
                                           @"Like" : @"A3D16E", @"Star" : @"EC6C58", @"StatusBar" : @"Light"}};
    themes.themes = myTheme;
        [themes saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if(succeeded){
                NSLog(@"done");
            }
    }];
```

Link to the error picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/otrym.png

However, since I was using the Back4App dashboard with Parse, I manually added my own Object that matched everything, to test if I could query for it. When I queried with:

```
    PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: kCloudThemesModelClassName];
    [query whereKeyExists:@"themes"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(error) {
            completion(nil, error);
            return;
        }
        if(objects){
            NSLog(@"found");
            if(objects.count > 0) {
                completion(((CloudThemes *)objects[0]).themes, nil);
            } else {
                completion(nil, nil);
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"No objects found");
            completion(nil, nil);
        }
    }];
```

I always end up with No objects found.

I'm not sure how this is happening, any thoughts?

Comment: Try to take a look at [this](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/blob/master/Parse/Tests/Unit/ObjectSubclassTests.m) test case. It shows how to create a custom object in objective c. In addition to that, make sure that your `themes` field is of object type on dashboard.

Comment: Thank you! @DaviMacêdo . I just resolved this. Turns out I was calling the PFQuery inside AppDelegate, before I had set up Parse.